# How to eliminate the regularizing function item?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\mathbf{f} \in W^{1,q}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, 
$J \in L^p (\mathbb{R}^n)$, with $1 \leq p,q \leq \infty$, 
and  $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1$, $\rho_{\epsilon}$ be a regularizing kernel for $\epsilon > 0$,
$
\rho_{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{\epsilon ^n} \rho(\frac{\cdot}{\epsilon}),
$
with $\rho \in C^{\infty}_0 (\mathbb{R}^n)$, 
$\rho (\cdot) \geq 0$, 
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \rho dx = 1$ 
and the compact support $supp~ \rho = B_1(0)$, where $B_1 (0) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is 
the ball with the center $0$ and the radius $1$.

Prove the inequality
\begin{eqnarray*}
&& \int_{B_R}  | \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} J(y) (\mathbf{f} (y) - \mathbf{f} (x)) \cdot \nabla \rho_{\epsilon}(x-y) dy | dx \\
& \leq & C \| J \|_{L^p (B_{R+1})} \Big \{ \int_{B_{R+1}} dx \int_{|x-y| \leq \epsilon } \{ \frac{|\mathbf{f} (y) - \mathbf{f} (x)|}{\epsilon} \}^q dy \Big \}^{\frac{1}{q}}
\end{eqnarray*}

I know the Holder's inequality should be used. But I don't know how to eliminate the item $\nabla \rho_{\epsilon}(x-y) $.

Could someone give help? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

---

The inequality should be
\begin{eqnarray*}
&& \int_{B_R}  | \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} J(y) (\mathbf{f} (y) - \mathbf{f} (x)) \cdot \nabla \rho_{\epsilon}(x-y) dy | dx \\
& \leq & C \| J \|_{L^p (B_{R+1})} \Big \{ \int_{B_{R+1}} dx \int_{|x-y| \leq \epsilon } \{ \frac{|\mathbf{f} (y) - \mathbf{f} (x)|}{\epsilon} \}^q \frac{1}{\epsilon^n} dy \Big \}^{\frac{1}{q}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: You can use the connection between $\rho_\epsilon$ and $\rho$ to derive an estimate of $\nabla \rho_\epsilon$, can't you?

Comment: Yes, I have $\nabla \rho_{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n+1} } \nabla \rho $. But, there is a $ \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n+1} } $ which I don't know how to deal with.  Would you please explain it more specificly?